# Why this PendingIntent Not working on android 12

Tags: android, crash, android-pendingintent, android-12

Please read the PendingIntent Below and correct it for my project.

Broadcast class:

```
intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
```

MainAcitivity:

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Correct the PendingIntent because app crashing on android 12

Logcat:

> ```
> FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-6 08-11 16:41:53.695 E/AndroidRuntime( 6004): Process: com.sk.spico, PID: 6004 08-11 16:41:53.695
> ```
>
> E/AndroidRuntime( 6004): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> com.sk.spico: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of
> FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a
> PendingIntent. 08-11 16:41:53.695 E/AndroidRuntime( 6004): Strongly
> consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some
> functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it
> needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles. 08-11 16:41:53.695
> E/AndroidRuntime( 6004):  at
> android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:382) 08-11
> 16:41:53.695 E/AndroidRuntime( 6004):     at
> android.app.PendingIntent.getActivityAsUser(PendingIntent.java:465)
> 08-11 16:41:53.695 E/AndroidRuntime( 6004):   at
> android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:451) 08-11
> 16:41:53.695 E/AndroidRuntime( 6004):     at
> android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:415) 08-11
> 16:41:53.695 E/AndroidRuntime( 6004):     at
> com.facebook.ads.internal.go.f(SourceFile:112) 08-11 16:41:53.695
> E/AndroidRuntime( 6004):  at
> com.facebook.ads.internal.hb.a(SourceFile:60) 08-11 16:41:53.695
> E/AndroidRuntime( 6004):  at
> com.facebook.ads.internal.hb.a(SourceFile:52) 08-11 16:41:53.695
> E/AndroidRuntime( 6004):  at
> com.facebook.ads.internal.mo.a(SourceFile:113) 08-11 16:41:53.695
> E/AndroidRuntime( 6004):  at
> com.facebook.ads.internal.mo.a(SourceFile:89) 08-11 16:41:53.695
> E/AndroidRuntime( 6004):  at
> com.facebook.ads.internal.mo.c(SourceFile:82) 08-11 16:41:53.695
> E/AndroidRuntime( 6004):  at
> com.facebook.ads.internal.hu.(SourceFile:137) 08-11 16:41:53.695
> E/AndroidRuntime( 6004):  at
> com.facebook.ads.internal.hw.(SourceFile:98) 08-11 16:41:53.695
> E/AndroidRuntime( 6004):  at
> com.facebook.ads.internal.hw.a(SourceFile:76) 08-11 16:41:53.695
> E/AndroidRuntime( 6004):  at
> com.facebook.ads.internal.gu.c(SourceFile:287) 08-11 16:41:53.695
> E/AndroidRuntime( 6004):  at
> com.facebook.ads.internal.gu.a(SourceFile:102) 08-11 16:41:53.695
> E/AndroidRuntime( 6004):  at
> com.facebook.ads.internal.er.initialize(SourceFile:29) 08-11
> 16:41:53.695 E/AndroidRuntime( 6004):     at
> com.facebook.ads.internal.dynamicloading.DynamicLoaderFactory$1.run(SourceFile:17)
> 08-11 16:41:53.695 E/AndroidRuntime( 6004):   at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)

Review CODE and solve issue

Answer (score 0):

Probably because I think that `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` is not compatible with `PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE`

`PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` is:-

> Flag indicating that if the described PendingIntent already exists, then keep it but replace its extra data with what is in this new Intent.

But `PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE` is:-

> Flag indicating that the created PendingIntent should be immutable.

i.e cannot be changed, thus cannot be updated

It's fairly common problem Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) to choose the wrong type of PendingIntent

Try using `PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE` instead and then the Pending Intent can be changed by the Update.

Comment: Both are not working

Comment: error also blongs to facebook ads

Comment: I suggest you raise a bug agains Facebook, if there is a problem with their code.

Comment: I think it should be PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE